# Adding polygon feature from one data to another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, digitizing

I am using ArcGIS 10.2. I have two polygon files: Data A and Data B. I am trying to add a couple polygons from Data B to Data A. In the editing mode, is there a way to pick the shape of a polygon (Data B) and add it into Data A?
(without using the trace tool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In editing mode,

1. Select polygon to be copied.
2. "Edit > Copy" or "right click > Copy" or "hit Ctrl + C".
3. "Edit > Paste" or "right click > Paste" or "hit Ctrl + V". When you do this, a small window appears.
4. Select target layer by this window, and click OK.

[image]